# Trying to rename bulk folders using standard tools

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I am trying to bulk rename many folders but for some reason my approach does not seem to work. I am trying to use the following script but it does nothing. I am new to programming so any suggestions are appreciated.
These are the folder names that i have.

```
test.custom.tmp         untitledfolder.custom.tmp   wis.custom.tmp
```

I need them renamed to

```
test untitledfolder wis
```

I am using the following script but it does nothing.

```
while read line; do
  newname=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d '_')
  mv $line newname;
done < read
```

Here i created a file called read with all the foldernames that need renaming.

What is wrong with this script and also is there a better way to get this done?
Thanks.

Comment: Is `read` a file? What is the `done <  read` reading from? Also, what operating system are you using? Different systems have different tools available.

Comment: Is it `test untitled wis` or *`test untitledfolder wis`*.

Comment: How should name collisions be handled? I.e., what should happen with the two names `my.custom.name1` and `my.custom.name2`?

Comment: What standard are you referring to? The POSIX standard? Note that while `echo` is a POSIX command, [its behaviour is left mostly unspecified and in practice it's not portable](/q/65803). `read` is also a POSIX command, but [you're using it improperly here if the intent is to read a line from a file](/q/209123).

Comment: Apologies. I have added some more info and corrected the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda there wont be any name collisions. The folders are generated by a program which takes care of that.

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, it's likely to come out triangular or hexagonal or just explode in your face.   Use the [perl rename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=perl+rename) utility instead.  Or `rename` from util-linux or `mmv` or similar instead...but the perl rename is the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be:

```bash
$ for d in *.custom.tmp/; do 
    echo mv -- "$d" "${d%%.*}"
  done
mv -- test.custom.tmp/ test
mv -- untitledfolder.custom.tmp/ untitledfolder
mv -- wis.custom.tmp/ wis
```

Once you are sure that's the result you want, remove the `echo`.

---

The `${d%%.*}` is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html), precisely:

> **${parameter%word}**
>
> **${parameter%%word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the pattern
> matches a trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then
> the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the
> shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching
> pattern (the ‘%%’ case) deleted.

In this case it takes the string for example `test.custom.tmp` and removes everythig after the first `.`.

Comment: One may possibly want to restrict the loop to `*.custom.tmp/`, if there are other names containing dots in the directory.

Comment: Good, added to the answer @Kusalananda.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have seen ${d%%.*} type of code  before on the internet . can you please explain how this works? I mean what this %% is supposed to mean and how it knows to remove .custom.tmp instead of just .tmp

Comment: @ranjitabraham You are welcome, added an explanation from the bash manual in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your aproach, you can do something like:

```
while read line; do
  newname=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1 -d '.');
  mv $line $newname;
done < read
```

Just keep in mind that your delimiter is a point (`-d '.'`), and also use the `$newname` as a variable, not as a string.

This corrects your scripts errors, but for a better approach you can use [@schrodingerscatcuriosity answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704506/343267).

Comment: See [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123) and [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/590210)

Comment: Thats why my script didnt work. I was calling newname as a string. sorry.. noob. Just started doing scripting a few weeks back.